# app.config transformation - nlog rules logger replace not works

Tags: app-config, nlog, xdt-transform

in *App.config* I have nlog section:

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <variable name="logDirectory" value="C:\AppsLog" />

    <targets>
      <target name="LogDebugTarget" ... />
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="LogDebug" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="LogDebugTarget" />
      <logger name="LogInfo" minlevel="Info" writeTo="LogInfoTarget" />
      <logger name="LogError" minlevel="Error" writeTo="LogErrorTarget,LogErrorTargetEmail" />
    </rules>

  </nlog>
```

in *App.debug.config* I want to replace:

```xml
<logger name="LogError" minlevel="Error" writeTo="LogErrorTarget,LogErrorTargetEmail" />
```

with:

```xml
<logger name="LogError" minlevel="Error" writeTo="LogErrorTarget" />
```

but left rest nodes untouched:

```xml
  <logger name="LogDebug" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="LogDebugTarget" />
  <logger name="LogInfo" minlevel="Info" writeTo="LogInfoTarget" />
```

so in *App.debug.config* I have written:

```xml
  <nlog>
    <rules>
      <add xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="LogError" minlevel="Error" writeTo="LogErrorTarget" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

but it does not replace anything - just left whole content of oryginal `<nlog>` node

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few mistakes: you lost `namespaces` in the transform file and wrote incorrect xml `tag` that you want to swap.
So it's very easy to fix:

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <rules>
    <logger xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" name="LogError" minlevel="Error" writeTo="LogErrorTarget" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```